# Reading continuously from stdin

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, stdin, do-while

I just started to learn C so sorry if I missed something obvious. As a practice I wanted to write my own posix `cat` and I nearly got it working as it should, but it doesn't read more than one file from stdin when there are no arguments.

This is the expected behavior (Ignore this, as this is a Zsh feature that I didn't know about):

```
$ cat < hello.txt < world.txt
hello
world
$
```

However my `cat` crashes with a "segmentation fault" (I had a version that didn't crash but it didn't output anything either)

Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "u")) != EOF) {
        switch(opt) {
            case 'u':
                /* Make the output un-buffered */
                setbuf(stdout, NULL);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    int i = 0, fildes, fs = 0;

    do {
        /* Check for operands, if none or operand = "-". Read from stdin */
        if (argc == 0 || !strcmp(argv[i], "-")) {
            fildes = STDIN_FILENO;
        } else {
            fildes = open(argv[i], O_RDONLY);
        }

        /* Check for directories */
        struct stat fb;
        if (!fstat(fildes, &fb) && S_ISDIR(fb.st_mode)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cat: %s: Is a directory\n", argv[i]);
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        /* Get file size */
        fs = fb.st_size;

        /* If bytes are read, write them to stdout */
        char buf[fs];
        while ((read(fildes, buf, fs)) > 0)
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, fs);

        /* Close file if it's not stdin */
        if (fildes != STDIN_FILENO)
            close(fildes);

        i++;
    } while (argv[i] != NULL || argc == 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `This is the expected behavior:` Did you mean to write it without `<` ? `char buf[fs];` ugh, use dynamic allocation, it may be too big to be on stack. `Close file if it's not stdin` Just close stdin too, no need to check. `} while (argv[i] != NULL || argc == 0);` What if there are no files passed, like in your example? the `cat < something < something` is executing `cat` without any arguments.

Comment: You are passing no arguments.  The `'<'` character redirects stdin from a file.  The shell does not pass it as a command line argument.

Comment: @KamilCuk the GNU `cat` works the same way as my "expected behavior", that's why I'm trying to achieve the same behavior. The posix standard says that `cat` shouldn't close and then re-open it's stdin so I'm trying to follow that. As for `buf[fs]` that's was the best solution that I could come up with after some *quick* googling

Comment: What is the content of `hello.txt` `world.txt` files?

Comment: @stark I know, I'm trying to make the `do-while` loop read more that one file from the stdin, when there are no `file` arguments supplied as a `cat` should do, because now it reads just one and segment faults if there are more

Comment: @KamilCuk "hello" and "world" respectively

Comment: You can't redirect stdin more than once

Comment: Then  it is impossible that `cat  < hello.txt < world.txt` prints `hello world`. It should print only `world`.

Comment: @KamilCuk then GNU cat is magick or idk https://imgur.com/a/S99dFkj

Comment: Whatever that is, it is not a bash shell.

Comment: @stark perhaps it is not? :)

Comment: @stark At a guess, the shell is zsh, where (unless the [`multios` option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios) is turned off) `foo <a <b` is equivalent to `cat a b | foo` and `foo >a >b` is equivalent to `foo | tee a b >/dev/null`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' didn't know about that! sorry about the confusion

Comment: In any case, stdin sees a single stream.  At EOF all input has been processed.  The multiple externals files are not visible to the program.

Answer (score 2):

When you code compiled with gcc with `-fsanitize=address` code shows:

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==604950==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x7ffea6d94000 (pc 0x55b9a63dfb57 bp 0x7ffea6d90d20 sp 0x7ffea6d90b80 T0)
    #0 0x55b9a63dfb57 in main /tmp/10/1.c:56
    #1 0x7f1403c17b24 in __libc_start_main (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x27b24)
    #2 0x55b9a63df3dd in _start (/tmp/.ccrun.604893.exefile+0x23dd)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow /tmp/10/1.c:56 in main
==604950==ABORTING
```

Th snippet:

```
do {
   ...
   ++i;
} while (argv[i] != NULL || argc == 0);       // HERE!
```

`argc` is always `0`, so `while(...)` is always executing, yet `++i` is always incrementing. `argc[...]` is accessed out of bounds, until you get a segfault.

I think you should change it to `} while (argv[i] != NULL && argc != 0);`

Comment: This does solve the error, and so should `while(i < argc)` if I'm not mistaken. But I still have issues with the stdin: I can not pipe to my `cat` and it exits when there are no arguments or input from stdin which it shouldn't. IDK what's going on with the piping, and IDK how to solve the second issue w/o potential stack-overflow, any pointers are welcomed (or should I just create a new question?)

Comment: Should `argc==0`, `argv[i]` `do { ... ++i  } while (argv[i] != NULL && argc != 0);` is UB with `argv[i]`.  Better to reverse order or use `while {}`